# Finding minimum distance between two points

Tags: java, algorithm

I have *M* points which are connected by *N* lines. The next *N* lines of input contains distance between different pair of points. I want to find the sum of minimum distance between each pair of points.

**Sample Input:**

```
5 6
1 2 23
1 3 5
2 3 3
2 4 12
3 4 5
4 5 2
```

**Sample Output:**

```
31
```

**Explanation:**

[image]

d(1,2) = 5+3=8

d(1,3) = 5

d(2,3) = 3

d(2,4) = 3+5=8

d(3,4) = 5

d(4,5) = 2

sum = 8+5+3+8+5+2 = 31

**Edit 1:**

I have converted the wighted graph into adjancey matrix using the following code:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int m = in.nextInt();
    int[][] vertices = new int[m][m];

    for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
            vertices[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i < m; i++){
            int a = in.nextInt();
            int b = in.nextInt();
            int c = in.nextInt();
            vertices[a][b] = c;
            vertices[b][a] = c;
    }
```

Now how can i find the shortest distance between any two points given there exists a line joining them?

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? We cannot do the entire thing for you!

Comment: Why aren't d(1,4), d(1,5), d(2,5), d(3,5) included in the sum?

Comment: @SujeetSinha just edited my question. I shall be grateful if you could help me

Comment: @ajb because there is no line given in the input that joins them (directly)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Floyd-Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) to construct the matrix of all pairs shortest pathes. Now add all values in the matrix and divide by 2, because you will count each distance twice.

The pseudocode on a wiki page is more than enough to convert it to java.